# Email syncing on WiFi only

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, active-sync

I have a user with a new Nexus 5X. It is configured to sync his personal (Gmail) email and work (Exchange) email (using the Gmail app). Gmail syncs fine; however, Exchange will only sync when connected to WiFi. Even a manual sync will not download Exchange email.

I have installed all updates (he is on Android 6.0.1, security patch level March 1, 2016). I confirmed that "restrict background data" is NOT enabled for anything. Turned off battery optimization (Doze) for Exchange Services & Gmail. I've tried various sync settings for the Exchange account (Push, 15 min, 30 min, etc). No luck. Exchange email will not download while on cell service, but Gmail will. As soon as I have a WiFi connection, the Exchange email downloads.

Not sure what to try next; any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Caf:
I had what I thought was the same issue upon receiving the 6.0.1 update this past week on my Galaxy  S5. However, I realized that I was plugging my phone in when I returned to the office which was disabling power saver mode which I typically leave on. After turning this off, I was able to sync over the mobile network. Interestingly, changing the doze settings had no effect (I tried them on and off with the power saver). I would see if your user leaves the power saver mode on as that was not explicitly mentioned above.